# How to send push notifications to iOS devices using GCM on Java based application server

Tags: java, ios, cordova, notifications

I need some help to understand how to send push notifications to iOS devices using GCM on Java based application server.

On the server side I am using gcm-server jar to send notifications to android devices and its working fine. I need to use same code base (i.e. Java code not Objective C) to send notification to iOS devices. How do i achieve this?

Also, I have got p12 certificate enable for push notification which is a prerequisite for iOS push notification. Now where do I need to use this p12 file on GCM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good library on github:

[java-apns on gitub](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)

It comes with documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But our intention to use GCM is that we can use same code base for both android and iOS devices. Therefore I want to understand what are the steps to use GCM for iOS devices.

Comment: According to http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2016/01/29/quickstart-google-cloud-messaging-ios/ we need to do some work on Xcode to register project with Google.  But till now I haven't coded anything Xcode.... so is this required for every iOS app to receive push notification from GCM.

Comment: Thanks Joseph... till now all the blogs and documentation i have visited (including the link u mentioned above) says that I need to configure Xcode project and install Cocoa Pods for this. I have till now I have used intellij IDE for my app... there is no Xcode project for my app. Does this mean creating an Xcode project is mandatory for receiving push notification from GCM on iOS devices?